# Subview autolayout constraints in init

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a custom UIView which is a subclass of UIScrollView. In the init(_ frame) method I add a subview as follows:

```
    contentView = ContentView()
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.addSubview(contentView)

    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    // create contentView's Width and Height constraints
    cvWidthConstraint = contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
    cvHeightConstraint = contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
           
    // activate them
    cvWidthConstraint.isActive = true
    cvHeightConstraint.isActive = true

    cvWidthConstraint.constant = timelineWidth //It's non-zero
    cvHeightConstraint.constant = 2.0*frame.height
```

The problem is it takes time for the contentView frame to be updated. It certainly doesn't get updated in init(_ frame) call. When exactly does contentView frame gets set and how do I catch the event of frame updation?

Comment: First, your code doesn't show the `contentView` being added as a subview. Second, what do you mean *"it takes time for the contentView frame to be updated"*? Third, you should be constraining the `contentView` to the scroll view's `contentLayoutGuide`. However, your question as posted is missing the info needed to explain what's happening and to give you an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I missed posting addSubview line without which obviously code will crash, added it now. This initialisation happens in init(_frame). I need contentView.frame in the same call but it is CGRect.zero in this call. It doesn't get setup until layoutSubviews gets invoked.

Comment: *"I need contentView.frame in the same call..."* -- Why? From the code you posted, and your description, you have nothing in the scrollView to scroll. If you are adding subviews to `contentView`, give them proper constraints so `contentView` will hold them and the scrollable area will be handle automatically.

Comment: Because there is an external view outside of this UIScrollView whose frame is synched to this contentView frame. It needs to be redrawn whenever the contentView frame changes.

Comment: With the code you've shown, you've set `contentView` width and height constraints to Zero. When do you expect the frame to change? What is this "external view" and what is it constrained to? We can't guess at how to help you without you telling us what you're trying to do.

Comment: I guess you have access to this repository in github. I update the constraints somewhere down in the same init(frame) call but still it doesn't get updated before call layoutSubviews call.

Answer (score 1):

Inside

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  // to do  
}
```

You get parent view actual frame , but keep in mind as it's called multiple times

Comment: Yes I am using that by using a bool to test whether the setup has been done or not for the first time. Because layoutSubviews will be called many times. Seems like a workaround though, not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

before setting the constraints, I would make sure the view is added to the parent view, like “self.addSubview(contentView)”. If “self” view is already added to the view hierachy, then the contentView layout will be effective right away. Alternatively, you can override the method viewDidMoveToSuperview, and there you check if the superview is not nil and, if so, you initialize and plug the subview contentView to it